# Calculate number of changes of a variable per individual in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

Might be a very simple question to ask but I struggle to solve this problem in r.
I have a dataset containing four variables: ID (for identifying the participants ), Type (with 1 value this time ), Decision (A or B) and Feedback (0 or 1). The data set for two participants looks like this:

```
ID   Type    Decision    Feedback
1     1       A           0
1     1       A           0
1     1       B           1
1     1       B           1
1     1       B           0
2     1       A           0
2     1       A           1
2     1       A           1
2     1       A           0
2     1       B           1
etc...
```

I want to calculate the number of changes in the decision process as a function of the previous feedback. In other words, if the participant choose A and received a negative feedback, will  she/he choose A again (Stay) or B (Shift). So my code is the following for one participant:

```
Stay=0
Shift=0  

for(i in 2:length(mydf$Type)){  
    if(mydf$Decision[i] == "A" && mydf$Feedback[i-1]==1 && mydf$Decision [i-1] == "A" ){
    Stay= Stay+1
    }
    else if(mydf$Decision [i] == "B" && mydf$Feedback[i-1]==1 && mydf$Decision [i-1] == "B" ){
    Stay= Stay+1
    }
    else if(mydf$ Decision [i] == "A" && mydf$Feedback[i-1]==1 && mydf$Decision [i-1] == "B" ){
    Shift= Shift+1
    }
    else if(mydf$Decision [i] == "B" && mydf$Feedback[i-1]==1 && mydf$Decision [i-1] == "A" ){
    Shift= Shift+1
    }
}
```

However, my data frame contains 20 participants and I don’t know how to extend my code to get the number of stays and shifts for each participant (i.e., to get something like this at the end):

```
#ID    Stay    Shift
#1     10      10
#2     16      4
#etc...
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you post the result of `dput(head(mydf, 50))`, which would create a reproducible version of the first 50 rows of your data frame and make it much easier to answer?

Comment: How does the feedback factor into whether they stay with A or B?

Comment: For the example you've shown, for `ID=1`, could you explain what `stay` and `shift` would be?

Comment: Stay and Shift are values. If the participant chooses A s/he receives pos or neg feedback. Depending on the feedback, s/he can decide to choose A again (which is a stay) or go for the other option (this would be a shift). I would like to count the number of stays and shifts during the experiment.

Comment: So in the case of ID=1, there are 5 trials, the second is a stay, since the participant chose A after choosing A initially, but the third decision is a shift, since s/he chose B. The next two decisions are also stays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best done using `ddply` in the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package (you'll have to install it), which splits up a data frame based on one of the columns and does some analysis on each, before recombining into a new data frame.

First, write a function `num.stay.shift` that calculates your stay and shift values given a single subset of the data frame (explained in comments):

```
num.stay.shift = function(d) {
    # vector of TRUE or FALSE for whether d$Feedback is 1
    negative.feedback = (head(d$Feedback, -1) == 1)
    # vector of TRUE or FALSE for whether there is a change at each point
    stay = head(d$Decision, -1) == tail(d$Decision, -1)
    # summarize as two values: the number that stayed when feedback == 1,
    # and the number that shifted when feedback == 1
    c(Stay=sum(stay[negative.feedback]), Shift=sum(!stay[negative.feedback]))
}
```

Then, use `ddply` to apply that function to each of the individuals within the data frame, splitting it up by ID:

```
print(ddply(tab, "ID", num.stay.shift))
```

On the subset of the data frame you show, you would end up with

```
#   ID Stay Shift
# 1  1    2     0
# 2  2    2     0
```

Comment: +1 for using -1 with `head` and `tail`. I had a similar answer using `embed`, but this is cleaner.

Comment: @David Robinson thanks for the very fast answer. I need some time to fully understand your solution, since the result appears to be incorrect. In ID=1, for instance, there are 3 stays and 1 shift. But I think, I can figure out now. Many thanks!!

Comment: @user2205323: You said you wanted the stays and shifts only in the cases where the previous feedback was `1` (isn't that why you had the code `mydf$Feedback[i-1]==1`?) In that case, I believe the output I gave is correct

Comment: @user2205323: Did you want to split up the Stays and Shifts based on the previous feedback? If you just want all of the stays and shifts regardless of feedback, just change the last line of the function to `c(Stay=sum(stay), Shift=sum(!stay))`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: The `embed` function is one of those hidden gems in R. Would like to see it in action here.

Comment: @David Robinson: Yes, you are right, again. It took me a while to understand your code, now I am really amazed about how compact it is! I have just added these lines: `positive.feedback = (head(d$Feedback, -1) == 0)` so now I have the values for pos and neg feedbacks.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: an alternative that I decided was too obscure was `stay = diff(as.numeric(d$Decision)) == 0`

Comment: @DWin I posted my `embed` answer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson still, clearer than `embed`. I guess the problem with having a gem or two in your bag is the temptation to show them off when something simpler would suffice.

Comment: @David Robinson: I just want to share this, maybe it is useful for someone, who not only wants to calculate the number of changes but also wants to use the values (i.e. if you have additional variable like a corresponding reaction time-RT for each decision). The way to do it (for stays and shifts) is pretty simple when we modify David's code by adding a line like this: `RT=(tail(d$RT, -1))`, and `c(stay=mean(RT[stay]), shift=mean(RT[!stay]))`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a nice breakdown by ID and Feedback:

```
  library(data.table)
  X <- data.table(mydf, key="ID")

  X[, list(Dif=abs(diff(as.numeric(Decision))),  
          FB=head(Feedback, -1))
        , by=ID][,list(Shifted=sum(Dif), Stayed=length(Dif)-sum(Dif)), by=list(ID,FB)]

  #     ID FB Shifted Stayed
  #  1:  1  0       1      1
  #  2:  1  1       0      2
  #  3:  2  0       1      1
  #  4:  2  1       0      2
```

---

or if you don't want the breakdown by `Feedback`, it is even more succinct:

```
X[ , {Dif=abs(diff(as.numeric(Decision))); 
     list(Shifted=sum(Dif), Stayed=length(Dif)-sum(Dif))}
  , by=list(ID)]

#      ID Shifted Stayed
# 1:  1       1      3
# 2:  2       1      3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly hairier alternative using the `embed` function, as mentioned in the comments to @DavidRobinson's answer.

```
d<-read.table(text="ID   Type    Decision    Feedback
1     1       A           0
1     1       A           0
1     1       B           1
1     1       B           1
1     1       B           0
2     1       A           0
2     1       A           1
2     1       A           1
2     1       A           0
2     1       B           1", header=TRUE)

do.call(rbind,
    by(d, d$ID, function(x) {
        f <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1
        stay <- apply(embed(as.vector(x$Decision), 2), 1, f)
        neg.feedback <- x$Feedback[1:nrow(x)-1] == 1
        c(Stay = sum(stay & neg.feedback), Shift = sum((! stay) & neg.feedback))
    })
)
#   Stay  Shift
# 1    2      0
# 2    2      0
```